# Is JavaScript support default parameters in its functions?

Tags: javascript

I want to make default parameter in javascript , so can i ?

```
jm.toInt = function (num, base=10) {
    return parseInt(num,base);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters ... see the browser support...

Answer (score 4):

With a **logical or**, default values are possible.

```
jm.toInt = function (num, base) {
    return parseInt(num, base || 10);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ofcourse there is a way!

```
function myFunc(x,y)
{
   x = typeof x !== 'undefined' ? x : 1;
   y = typeof y !== 'undefined' ? y : 'default value of y';
   ...
}
```

in your case

```
    jm.toInt = function(num, base){
       return parseInt(num, arguments.length > 1 ? base: 'default value' );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

ES6 support [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters), but ES5 not, you can use transpilers (like [babel](https://babeljs.io/)) to use ES6 today

Answer (score 2):

It is [part of ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters), but as of now, [not widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters#Browser_compatibility) so you can do something like

```js
jm.toInt = function(num, base) {
  return parseInt(num, arguments.length > 1 ? base : 10);
}
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to using `arguments.length > 1 ?` rather then simply `base ?`

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin none... you can use any of the above formats in this case....

Answer (score 0):

Use `typeof` to validate that arguments exist (brackets added to make it easier to read):

```
jm.toInt = function (num, base) {
    var _base = (typeof base === 'undefined') ? 10 : base
    return parseInt(num, _base);
}
```